# SQL Database Clone / Mirror

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Please excuse my ignorance as SQL 'stuff' isn't really my thing, indeed I'm so ignorant I'm not even sure what terms I should be using! Just after someone to point me in the right direction.

I've got a website (on the cloud) that pulls its data in from a locally housed database. The problem is that periodically the site can't connect to the DB and the site then falls over.

So what I'd like to be able to do is (somehow) create a copy of the DB on the cloud (that the site can then use as it's datasource) that's 'connected' the local one. So that when the local copy is amended by the local business users then these changes will somehow ricochet up to the cloud copy and when the site updates the Cloud version this then filters down to the Local copy.

I have no clue if this is possible (out of the Microsoft SQL box). The goal is that if the connection between the cloud and the local copy was interrupted then the site would stay online as it's using the Cloud version for it's datasource and could continue to update/change and similarly the locally housed business systems would continue to operate as they're pointing the to local copy of the database.

And then when the connection came back online the databases would update each other.

Is this possible? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Sorry this is so long winded.

Thanks,
C

Comment: I am not skilled with MS SQL, but I believe you should focus into resolving the issue that cause your webserver to lose its database, than having a copy of the db somewhere else

Comment: That's the ideal solution. The problem is that the hosting company cannot find any reason that could cause the issue.

Comment: The real problem is the connection loss. Focus on that, not on a workaround for it. Even if you get the workaround working, what happens when the connection gets lost again while synchronizing ?

Comment: you can do some sort of mirroring across sites I think yes. I forget what it's called, but I'm sure you can find it if you google. I suspect it needs someone knowledgeable to configure it though. And I think really it's meant for disaster recovery purposes rather than your proposal of dual operation. This idea sounds horrible. For instance, what does it do if separate changes on the two databases conflict with each other? Better to sort the connectivity issues